# what is the difference between void example(); and void example; in abstract class in Dart Language?

Tags: dart

what is the difference between ***void example();*** and ***void example;*** in abstract class in Dart Language?

```
abstract class Test
{
void example1();
void example2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void` means that the value is not to be used and should therefore not be used. In most cases, we mark a method to return `void` when we want to indicate, that our method does not return anything.

So `example1()` is a method which signature indicates that the returned value is not to be used.

`example2` is a variable of the type `void`. This is really not that useful since we are to use the value of this variable since the type is `void` which, as previous described, indicates the value should not be used.

But because `void` is used as a type in Dart, you are allowed to have a variable of the type `void` even if it does not really make much sense.

If you really want to do something with it, you can do something strange as:

```
abstract class Test
{
  void example1();
  void example2;
}

class A extends Test {
  @override
  void example1() => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  void get example2 => print('Hello World');
}

void main() {
  A().example2;
}
```

Here we cannot use the value from `example2` for anything but we can still call some code when trying to access the property.

There are lot more details about the `void` type in the Dart Language Specification in the section "Type Void": https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf